# GA4 Custom Dimensions (not set)

Tags: google-analytics, dimensions, custom-dimensions

I added a custom parameter to my transactions. I am receiving data as when I go to Reports> Realtime>View user snapshot and click on an event I can see the parameter name and a value which is good. I can also see the value when I go to Reports>Engagement>Events and chose and event and select my parameter in the 'Events in last 30 minutes tab'. The issue comes when I go to Explore and make a Free Form with my parameter as a row or column as the column would simply show '(not set)' even though I know it is set from the before views that I mentioned

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will see a value of “not set” for a custom dimension during the first 48 hours after you create the custom dimension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).